# Overriding user injected by @CreatedBy Annotation in AuditorAware Implementation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Following is my implementation of AuditAware.

```
@Component
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Log
    private Logger logger;

    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {
        String user = "SYSTEM";
        try {
            final Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
            if (subject != null) {
                final Session session = subject.getSession(false);
                if (session != null) {
                    final User userObj = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
                    if (userObj != null) {
                        user = userObj.getUsername();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            this.logger.error("getCurrentAuditor", "No logged in user information found.", e);
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

As we know, The value of user returned by AuditorAwareImpl injected by Spring in attribute marked by @CreatedBy annotation as below.

```
@CreatedBy
@Column(name = "CREATED_BY", length = 150, nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String createdBy;
```

There are two problems I want to solve.

1. I am triggering a separate thread which saves
   thousands of objects in database. If session times out in between, session object becomes null and AuditAwareImpl throws error and hence background process errors out.
2. I also want to run few quartz Schedular related jobs in which in which session object is itself not available. But I still want to inject some hard coded user in that case. But how do I do it?

One thing that I have tried at individual object level, using following code is,

```
@Transient
private String overRiddenUser;

@PrePersist
public void updateCreatedBy(){
    if(overRiddenUser!=null){ 
        this.createdBy=overRiddenUser;
    }
}
```

I explicitly set `overRiddenUser="Admin"` whenever I want to override user injected by spring in createdBy and overwrite it using PrePersist method. But even this does not seem to work since before even I overwrite this value, spring tries to populate created by using value returned by AuditAware. If session is already expired by then the process errors outs! How do I solve this?

Comment: Just implement that in your `AuditorAwareImpl`. Also you are doing async work so you should actually pass the context to the executing thread not rely on having the Http Session available (assuming you are using Spring Security that has classes that support that out-of-the-box).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to above problems as below.

**Step 1**

I defined a bean as below that contains a HashMap. This map will store current thread name as key and mapped username as value.

```
public class OverRiddenUser {
Map<String,String> userThreadMap= new HashMap<>(); 
//add getters/setters
}
```

**Step 2**

Initialised this bean on startup in class annoted by `@Configuration`.

```
@Bean("overRiddenUser")
public OverRiddenUser overRideUser(){
    OverRiddenUser obj = new OverRiddenUser();
    return obj;
    // Singleton implementation can be done her if required 
}
```

**Step 3**

Auto wired this bean in the impl class where I want to override session user.

```
@Autowired
OverRiddenUser overRiddenUser;
```

Assigned a random name to currently running thread.

```
RandomString randomThreadName = new RandomString(9);
Thread.currentThread().setName(randomThreadName.toString());
```

And then put required user name for current thread in hashmap as below.

```
try {
    if(overRiddenUser!=null){
    overRiddenUser.getUserThreadMap().put(Thread.currentThread().getName(),"My Over ridden username");
    }

// Entire Database related code here

} catch (Exception e){

 // handle the exceptions thrown by code

} finally {
            //Perform clean up here
            if(overRiddenUser!=null){
                overRiddenUser.getUserThreadMap().remove(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4**

Then I modified AuditAwareImpl as below.

```
@Component
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Log
    private Logger logger;

    @Autowired
    OverRiddenUser overRiddenUser;

    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {

        String user = "SYSTEM";
        try {

            if(overRiddenUser!=null && overRiddenUser.getUserThreadMap()!=null && overRiddenUser.getUserThreadMap().get(Thread.currentThread().getName())!=null){
                user=overRiddenUser.getUserThreadMap().get(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }else{
                final Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
                if (subject != null) {
                    final Session session = subject.getSession(false);
                    if (session != null) {
                        final User userObj = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
                        if (userObj != null) {
                            user = userObj.getUsername();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            this.logger.error("getCurrentAuditor", "No logged in user information found.", e);
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

So if the currently running thread accesses AuditAwareImpl then it gets custom user name which was set for that thread. If this is null then it pulls username from session as it was doing earlier. Hope that helps.